# Git push timeout when using post-receive-email hook

Tags: eclipse, git, githooks, post-receive-email

---

I'm using Git control version system through Eclipse (Egit plugin).

I've configured the post-receive-email hook to trigger an email every time I push to the remote repository. The hook is working as expected (I got a new email on every change), but I have to "push" twice.

When I make the first push, it always fails with a timeout error

```
 ssh://user@server/path/to/repo.git: Read timed out after 30.000 ms
```

Then, with the second push, everything goes well, the remote repository is updated and I receive the email.

So, I want to know if there is a way to fix this behaviour, if I have to add something to hook configuration, or change something in Eclipse. I dont want to push my changes twice everytime.

Hope you can help me, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Goto Windows -> Team -> Preferences -> (in the 'type filter text' search for -> ) GIT.

You get the following window

[image: EGIT Remote Connection Timeout Configuration]

Change or increase you time so that you might not have trouble when the Push to Upstream takes time.

This timeout issue is completely related to the EGIT configuration, you don't have to mess with the GIT hooks.

I hope your problem will be resolved with this my friend